# Why Python reads columns of the .txt as a single column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, txt

I've just started learning Python and I need to open the dataset. The file is .txt. The problem is when I read the file, Python merges all its columns into one.

The original txt looks like this:

[image: this]

I write the code in the Jupyter-notebook.

```
datareader = pd.read_csv ('data.txt', delimiter=None, header=[1,2])
datareader
```

Python output looks like this:

[image: this]

What am I doing wrong? How to open the data correctly?

Comment: you need to add a delimiter ```delimiter=r"\s+"```

Comment: `delimiter=None` why? may be you want `header=None`

Comment: @YashShah thank you! I tried different delimiters but didn't come up with the one you offered . Now the file opens correctly